# How to convert Procreate brushes to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, designers, file-conversion, procreate

I have a brush file with the extension `.BRUSHSET`. I realized it belonged to Procreate software. Is there a way to convert it to a brush for Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

After downloading and checking out some Procreate brushes (.brush files), these appear to be zip archive files. So if you change the file extension to zip, and open the zip, you should be able to extract the PNG images contained within it. I assume .brushset is also similar - just a zip archive.

If you can get the images out, then you can use them to create custom brushes in Photoshop.

Comment: This is true, but I am losing the effect of displacement and more

Comment: All you can use inside the zip archives is the image files. Everything else such as effects would need to be recreated using Photoshop's Brush Settings. I highly doubt you'd be able to use the brush settings stored in the Procreate Brush.